# cucumber-js executes all scenarios but it gets stuck in the command propmt

Tags: node.js, npm, cucumber, integration

When I start the command to run cucumber, it executes all of the scenarios and all of them pass. However, when it finishes it doesn't exit the process, but remains stuck until I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. This is important as I want to use it as a command in Jenkins, and it happens that in Jenkins it wouldn't finish ever given what I have just mentioned.

[image]

As you can see, the expected behaviour is the one from my unit test. Just exit the process, without me having to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: I've never used cucumber so I'm not sure what the expected pattern is, but I know it is possible to programmatically end the node process with `process.exit()`

Comment: Thanks, JSONaLeo, I actually set a timer to execute it in order for it to work. Not optimal, but It will do the trick for now:  setTimeout(function() {
    process.exit();
  }, 1000);

Comment: definitely not optimal; I would check cucumber’s docs for some kind of `done()` function, which I know exists in other testing frameworks. Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

According to the ([CLI reference](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/cli.md#Exiting)), you should be able to add "--exit" to the end of your command. So for me, it like this:

```
npx cucumber-js features/ -r steps/ {other cli things} --exit
```

There's some helpful hints there on finding out why the issue is occurring and fixing it, as well.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

I was using the `AfterAll` GlobalHook to tear down my in memory database.
After changing it to `After` (after each scenario), my cucumber-js task exit normally

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. In my case, I was closing *context* under AfterAll hook:

```
AfterAll(async () => {
  await context.close();
});
```

solved by not doing this, just closed *browser* instead:

```
AfterAll(async () => {
  await browser.close();
});
```